# Spring MVC forwarding HTTP POST request to GET request handler in another controller

Tags: java, spring, jsp, model-view-controller

I am trying to get my controller to forward a POST request to another controller with some parameters:

```
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String processSubmit(@Valid Voter voter, BindingResult result, 
      //...
      request.setAttribute("firstName", voter.getFirstName());
      request.setAttribute("lastName", voter.getLastName());
      request.setAttribute("ssn", voter.getSsn());
      logger.info("VoterID exists, forwarding to /question/prepare");
      return "forward:/question/prepare";
```

The problem that I am facing is that /question/prepare points to a Controller method that handles only HTTP GET requests.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/prepare", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String prepareVoterBean(@RequestParam String firstName, 
        @RequestParam String lastName, @RequestParam String ssn, Model model) {
    logger.info("QuestionController got GET REQUEST for " + firstName + lastName + ssn);
    VoterBean bean = new VoterBean();
    bean.setFirstName(firstName);
    bean.setLastName(lastName);
    bean.setSsn(ssn);

    model.addAttribute("questions",bean);
    return "questionPage";
}
```

Is there a way to forward the request to prepareVoterBean as a HTTP GET request? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a way to forward the request to prepareVoterBean as a HTTP
>   GET request?

Try using `redirect:` prefix.

---

```java
return "forward:/question/prepare";
```

This is not POST. The following link might be useful: ["22.5.3 Redirecting to views" section](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-redirecting).

Comment: Using `redirect:` you tell the client to request another page where you redirected whant to redirect him to. But using `forward:` this happens transparently on the server side, so the client just get a different response without another request. It's important to know that difference!

Answer (score -1):

@Midnight Blue...

Change return type to `return "forward:/prepare";`