# How to change the forwarding mode in controller springmvc？

Tags: java, spring-mvc, post, forward

This controller is designed to move from one handler method to another. the I'm using the default request for a post.  How do I change it to request mode?  The second method receives only get items.

```
@RequestMapping("/activeVoucher")
public String activeVoucher(String businessId,Model model,String voucherId){
    vService.activeVoucher(voucherId);
    model.addAttribute("businessId", businessId);
    return "forward:enterManagement";
}

@RequestMapping(value="/enterManagement",method={RequestMethod.GET})
public String enterManagement(VoucherPage voucherPage,Model model){
    List<CardVoucher> vouchers = vService.findVouchersById(voucherPage);
    model.addAttribute("vouchers", vouchers);
    model.addAttribute("businessId",voucherPage.getBusinessId());
    //给voucherPage设置查询出的总记录数
    if(vouchers!=null)
    voucherPage.setCount(vouchers.size());
    model.addAttribute("voucherPage", voucherPage);
    return "pages/manage/manage";
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring MVC forwarding HTTP POST request to GET request handler in another controller](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15780540/spring-mvc-forwarding-http-post-request-to-get-request-handler-in-another-contro)

Comment: Repair poor sentence and phrase structure.